# TSQL Search date range

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a search form that is allowing you to enter any information you want into it and perform the search on that data.

Here is what the form looks like:

[image]

My goal is to allow them to enter a start and end date. However, they could chose to only enter one or the other. In this case, I need my stored procedure to handle it correctly.

If the end date is empty, the end date will just become today's date. If the start date is empty, we could do any date (sqls default date for example which would include everything.

The `awardDate` is that field that is being searched. If both dates are entered, then it would need to be the range `between start and end`

Below is my current stored procedure:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.[awardID],
    A.[awardDescription],
    convert(varchar,cast(A.[awardValue] as money),1) as awardValue,
    CONVERT (VARCHAR (10), A.[awardDate], 101) AS awardDate,
    CONVERT (VARCHAR (10), A.[timestamp], 101) AS timestamp,
    B.[FirstName] + ' ' + B.[LastName] as empName,
    B.[ntid] AS empNTID,
    C.[awardType] as awardTypeName,
    D.[locationName],
    E.[awardStatusName]
FROM   taxTracker AS A
   INNER JOIN
   empTable AS B
   ON A.[employee] = B.[empID]
   INNER JOIN
   taxTrackerAwardTypes AS C
   ON A.[awardType] = C.[awardTypeID]
   INNER JOIN taxTrackerLocations as D
   ON A.[awardLocation] = D.[id]
   INNER JOIN taxTrackerStatuses as E
   ON A.[awardStatus] = E.[awardStatusID]
WHERE  ((A.[employee] IN (SELECT ParamValues.x2.value('empID[1]', 'VARCHAR(60)')
          FROM   @employees.nodes('/employees/employee') AS ParamValues(x2)))
    OR (ISNULL(@awardType, '') <> ''
        AND A.[awardType] LIKE '%' + @awardType + '%')
    OR (ISNULL(@awardStatus, '') <> ''
        AND A.[awardStatus] LIKE '%' + @awardStatus + '%'))
FOR    XML PATH ('details'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('root');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
where (awarddate >= @startdate or @stardate is null)
and (awarddate <= isnull(@enddate, getdate())
```

Comment: Seems like everything is working except when I only put in a start date thats like a month prior to a record. It should start at that date and then get anything up until current date. Example: record is 2/1/2014 and I put in 1/1/2014 for my search. It should get anything between 1/1/2014 and today's date

Comment: Have you tried writing dates in ISO format such as `20140101`, `20140102`? I made this [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b29e8) quickly to test the logic and it seems to be ok.

Comment: I got this error however none of the date fields are INT - `Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date`

Comment: This worked after all, my endDate was coming through as an empty string, not null. I added this to my vars `NULLIF(@awardStartDate, '')`

Answer (score 0):

```
Awarddate between isnull (@startdate, '19000101') and isnull (@enddate, getdate ())
```

Comment: the `getdate()` trick may work in this example but it wont work in cases with future schedule dates, and hardcoded '19000101' isn't an option in some scenarios either.

Comment: In this case you may use max of your future schedule date

Comment: See answer above from user TI, that is a general answer. And welcome to SO.